# Wait until AlertDialog shows

Tags: android, progressdialog

I have some buttons in a ListView. When the user clicks on a button, a custom **AlertDialog** pops up.
However, it **takes some time for the AlertDialog to show** because there are some images to load.

I want to make sure that the user **can not click on the button again** while the AlertDialog is loading, so I implemented a ProgressDialog that shows immediately onClick and dismisses as soon as the AlertDialog is there.

```
slotViewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("showing dialog...");
        progressDialog.show();

        loadDialogAndDoSomeAction();

        progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
});
```

The ProgressDialog still does not show. What am I doing wrong here? Are there better ways than this to prevent the user from doing something but wait?

Thanks in advance

Comment: enable and disable button accordingly

Comment: in fact, they are no real buttons but RelativeLayouts that are clickable

Comment: progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: set the visibility of the views

Comment: @MayuriRuparel: This does not solve the problem because the dialog does not even appear.

Comment: ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
slotViewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        
        progressDialog.setMessage("showing dialog...");
        progressDialog.show();

        loadDialogAndDoSomeAction();

        
     }
});

public void  loadDialogAndDoSomeAction();

{
 your code....

 progress.dismiss();
}

Comment: @Raghunandan: This would work but result in a strange UX. But thanks to both of you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by implementing an `onShowListener` on my `progressDialog`

```
slotViewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("showing dialog...");

    progressDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
           loadDialogAndDoSomeAction();
    }

    progressDialog.show();
});
```

I'm dismissing the `ProgressDialog` in `Alertdialog.onShow()` in `loadDialogAndDoSomeAction()`

Answer (score 0):

in your custom adapter you can override

```
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled ();
```

just keep a boolean as member for your adapter, and when you click on it change it to false.

Comment: looks like the approach I need, but doesn't work somehow. When onClick is invoked and I set `allItemsEnabled` to **false**, the buttons are still clickable for a second time before the dialog pops up

Comment: yeah Actually the documentation mentions it. Have you try to call notifyDataSetChanged on the Adapter's instance, after you set the value to false?

Comment: no wait, it should disable  all the elements when that method returns false. You have not to check for it. Can you edit your question and add relevant snipped of code?

Answer (score 0):

`Dialog` has an `OnShowListener`. You can implement this on your `AlertDialog`. Then dismiss your `ProgressDialog` there and make your `Views` clickable again or whatever you need.

```
myAlert.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface Dialog)
    {
         progressDialog.dismiss();
         // here you can make things clickable, etc...
    }
}):
```

[onShow Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnShowListener.html)

You will want to make your `ProgressDialog` a member variable so you can access it in the `onClick()` and in `onShow()`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna use this listener. But it doesn't solve the problem of **showing** the progressdialog immediately